# Htaccess: Rewrite rule with HTTPS authorization

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a WP plugin for exposing REST APIs. But to use APIs in a secure environment, I have used Oauth WP plugin as a dependency. But on some website hosting services, I am unable to get oauth flow to work. But I have updated following rule in htaccess of a WP site and it started working.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] (OLD)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L] (UPDATED)
```

Ref: https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/issues/81

It was working great on HTTP protocol, but when I tried same fix on the HTTPS site, it didn't work :( Please let me know if I have to update the rule to handle both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: It looks more like Apache configuration issue to me. When accessing SSL, apache may not be requesting authorization. Do post here if and when you find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

must to use OAuth ?, If not try with [JWT token plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)

Comment: Thanks, but it has same issue. we've to add `RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]` in the htaccess. Will it work of https also?

Comment: I used with REST, its works for me. try it and let know

Comment: what server engine are you using ? like nginx or apache or IIS

Comment: It's running on Apache